# Recording with two microphones in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, microphone, recording

Thanks for comming here.
I have two microphones connected to a PC and I would like to record sound from them simultaneously. Is it possible to do this at all? Any methods. Maybe I need to buy some device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of available recording devices using the microphone class

```
// Get list of Microphone devices and print the names to the log
void Start()
{
    foreach (var device in Microphone.devices)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + device);
    }
}
```

You can use this device list to create audio clips from each device

```
[SerializeField]
private AudioSource audioSource1;
[SerializeField]
private AudioSource audioSource2;

// Start recording with built-in Microphone and play the recorded audio right away
private IEnumerator Record()
{
    audioSource1.clip = Microphone.Start("<audio-device-1>", true, 10, 44100);
    audioSource2.clip = Microphone.Start("<audio-device-2>", true, 10, 44100);
}
```

Comment: You did `GetComponent<AudioSource>();` and they are both pointing to one AudioSource.  Changing clip of the-same AudioSource will overwrite the old one.... This will work with different/multiple AudioSource.